Reading an information from Excel Sheet instead of having it in the testConfig.properties
I'm building a suit automation test (Java, Selenium, TestNG, Apache POI). I have a configuration file .properties where I have the environment I use. Every time I comment one and use the other one, it depends from what I need in that moment and what test I need to run.
Is it possible to read this information about environments taking this data from an Excel sheet?

What are you trying to accomplish? It seems like editing and reading from a .properties file is way easier, simpler than spinning up code that reads from an Excel sheet and editing that. Are you trying to make changes without having to check in edited files to a repo? Do you have your suite execution trigger setup in Jenkins or anything like that? I would create a trigger for each of your environments and then just trigger the one for the appropriate environment. Each trigger would need it's own/separate config files, etc.
